# Method to analyse data in parallel in python pandas

Tags: python, pandas, parallel-processing, python-multiprocessing

I am doing some simple data analysis in python over 500,000 files taking file at a time. The analysis of each file takes around 1 second.My code is working fine but is it possible to take advantage of parallel computing in python to speed up things. Data size is not an issue as each file is of size 100Kb. It is reading/ writing files in for loop which takes up time. Here is what my code looks like.

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
from math import acos,sqrt,degrees,asin
import os
wd='C:/My_Folder/'
filelist=os.listdir(wd) # List of names of 500,000 files
for i in range(len(filelist))
    dt=pd.read_csv(wd+filelist[i]) # This line reads a csv file into pandas data frame
    newdata=myfunction(dt)         # This function does some simple manipulation on the data frame and returns the new data frame
    newdata.to_csv('C:/Output/'+filelist[i]) # This writes the new data frame into new csv file
```

The code is working absolutely fine, takes about a second to operate on each file. But I see my computer is using only one core , Can I speed this up by achieving parallelism

Comment: `Can I speed this up by achieving parallelism?` - that depends on whether reading the files or your data transformation is the bottleneck. If your transformation is the bottleneck you can easily parallelize your code using python's multiprocessing library https://docs.python.org/2/library/multiprocessing.html

Comment: @cel Can you please explain in a depth. AS far as I see the data transformation is not a bottleneck. Doing this transformation for 500,000 file takes time. I was looking if this can be done in parallel using 8 cores that I have in my PC

Comment: Read the section about worker pools here, that's probably what you want. https://docs.python.org/2/library/multiprocessing.html#using-a-pool-of-workers
You basically define a function that gets an input and output path and does the transformation. Then you read all the filenames and get the output paths. After that you create your pool with 8 worker threads and use `apply_async` to start your jobs.

Comment: *It is reading/ writing files in for loop* If as you say this is the case, it may just be that the OS is taking a long time creating file descriptors every time you open a new file. In this case parallelizing may not help ... If you are using iPython, you could try using `%time` magic to confirm where most time is spent? Then it may make more sense to try and `cat` all the files together, call `read_csv()` only once, and use some kind of a `groupby` operation on the resulting mega-dataframe.